# Relacionar mais de um valor da mesma linha com outra tabela (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

sou novo no Laravel e queria saber se tem como resolver meu problema sem ser no PHP puro, ou seja, usando os recursos próprio Laravel. Segue a situação atual e o que desejo fazer:

Tenho uma tabela chamada Departamentos, onde eu incluo o nome do departamento (coluna nome) e 1 ponto focal (coluna pontofocal_id), 1 gestor (coluna gestor_id) e 1 ou mais backups (coluna backup). Ao salvar o registro eu salvo os IDs dos pontofocal, backups e gestores que eu pego da Tabela usuários. Até ai normal, eu uso no meu arquivo App/Departamento o hasOne para a tabela usuários e consigo puxar o nome do usuário pelo ID inserido na tabela Departamentos.

```
public function pontofocal(){
    return $this->hasOne(Usuario::Class, 'id', 'pontofocal_id');
}

public function gestor(){
    return $this->hasOne(Usuario::Class, 'id', 'gestor_id');
}

public function backups(){
    return $this->hasOne(Usuario::Class, 'id', 'backup');
}
```

Porém a coluna Backup eu posso salvar mais de um ID no mesmo registro. Separo eles por vírgula.

No meu lista.blade.php eu usei um foreach dentro do outro foreach para pegar o valor do campo backup (exemplo: 1,4,5) para transformar num array contendo os IDS 1, 4 e 5, usando um explode e devolve esta informação para a variável $departameno->backup, para poder usar o relacionamento e pegar o campo name da tabela usuários conforme códio abaixo:

```
@foreach($departamentos as $departamento)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $departamento->nome }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $departamento->gestor->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $departamento->pontofocal->name }}</td>
                        @php
                            $arraybackups = explode(",",$departamento->backup);
                        @endphp
                        <td>
                            @foreach($arraybackups as $arraybackup)
                        @php
                            $departamento->backup = $arraybackup;
                        @endphp
                            {{ $departamento->backups->name }}
                            @endforeach
                        </td>
```

A princípio ele funciona mas parece que ele pega o valor do campo name apenas do primeiro ID e repete para os demais mesmo sendo IDs diferentes. Conforme abaixo:

[image: exemplo1]

Ao dar um echo para ver se estou gravando os IDs corretos extraídos do array, eu vejo que sim, estão corretos conforme abaixo. vejam q são IDs diferentes, mas ele me traz sempre o mesmo nome do primeiro ID da linha:

[image: exemplo2]

Existe alguma forma para fazer isso que eu quero?

Obrigado!

Comment: Você precisa fazer um junção dessas tabelas... mas, pelo visto como a coluna grava todos os Ids isso não é possivel ... repense as tabelas e guarde a informação de cada id em sua própria linha ... ou seja, guarda tudo no mesmo campo é um grande erro !!!

Comment: Olá Virgilio, obrigado por responder mas você está errado. Em alguns casos esta é a melhor maneira para agilizar o processo e diminuir o tamanho das tabelas. Eu já descobri como fazer o que preciso. Para isso eu usei um inner join das tabelas e no campo que eu preciso buscar os iDs usei o FIND_IN_SET() do MYSQL. Eles faz exatamente o que eu precisava. Ai depois Agrupei os resultados e usei o GROUP_CONCAT no campo que precisava. Tudo resolvido sem necessidade de criar outras tabelas. Abs

Comment: você resolveu o seu problema com duas funções, aí eu pergunto qual foi o custo!? Mas tudo bem em achar uma solução que hoje pode te ajudar e com alguma mudança pode ser prejudicial prefiro ainda utilizar um repositório bem organizado ...

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver o meu problema e estou postando aqui como resolvi.

Resolvi usando o FIND_IN_SET() função nativa do MYSQL. Ele busca os valores do campo e cruza com os da outra tabela e retorna tudo em uma linha separada. Ou seja, ele me retorna:

Financeiro   Back Up 01

Financeiro   Back Up 02

E assim por diante. Então depois eu fiz um GROUP BY para agrupar pelo nome do departamento e no campo NAME que traz os nomes do backup eu usei a função GROUP_CONCAT() função do próprio mysql tb.

Espero ter ajudado!

Abs